# How to extend the timespan of Google's calendar widget?

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, calendar, app-widgets, google-calendar

Or in other words: **How to show more dates in Google's calender widget?**

The next date I added to my Google calender is an appointment I have in eight days from now. The Google calender widget does not show this appointment. Right now there are no other dates added to this calendar.

So the problem is not, that there are to many dates. The problem is that the widget does not look into the future far enough. I want to see my next date, even if it is still a month to go.

1. How can I make the widget display dates that are scheduled farther in the future than it does now?
2. Is it possible to display all future dates?

   Of course the display of regularly repeated dates must be limited, but I would like to see at least the next scheduled of each one.
3. What is the reason, that this is not already the case?

   This seems really odd to me, because it does not look very complicated to find all the appointments in a database or sync them. To me it seems to be more work to limit those features this way.

P.S.: I just saw that the "date-list-view" of Google's calendar app (not the widget this time) does show dates, weeks ahead. I don't see any limitation. I would like the widget to behave the same way.

Comment: You might want to look for a 3rd party solution. There are a lot of calendar/agenda widgets available in the Playstore which are far more flexible in their configuration.

Comment: Thx for your comment. In general you are right, that I have to choose the the program satisfying my requirements best, but this is often hard, because all of them have advantages and disadvantages. In general I prefer to go with the default apps as far as I can. It is just frustrating to see those really artificial limitations.

Comment: Arrrrgh. I was so frustrated that I looked up the source of the Google calendar widget and it looks like they really HARDCODED it in, with magic numbers. Oh happy day! https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_calendar/blob/master/src/com/android/calendar/widget/CalendarAppWidgetModel.java#L259

Comment: I was a bit fast. It seems it is a little more complicated. Not sure if the posted LOC is relevant. This one may be relevant two: https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_calendar/blob/master/src/com/android/calendar/widget/CalendarAppWidgetService.java#L98 Anyway they should use magic numbers.

Answer (score 1):

I just downloaded off widget from Google Apps called simple calendar. once you install the widget on to your home screen then you go to the apps area and single tap on the simple calendar icon. takes you into the settings for the simple calendar widget and you will be amazed to see how many different ways you can customize the calendar. you go into one area where you can select how many days to see on your calendar. you can even mix items from several gmail accounts.

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts. A link to the app will make your answer more useful.

Comment: comment by coder284: *He might be referring to [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.anod.calendar) application*

Answer (score 0):

I lost *S. Planner Agenda* when upgrading to Jellybean. Can't find it anywhere at Playstore.

Just download [Agenda Widget for Android](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.roflharrison.agenda). I spent a few hours during some downtime mucking around with it, because it was addictive just working with the settings. It's free at the store. Can display up to 150 lines of future dates / events.   "everybody all the time" is listed as the creator.

They have a [paid version](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.roflharrison.agenda.plus) too; less than $2 AUD. I still can't work out the paid version benefits. I just wish they also brought back Google Calendar Sync, it synced my home computer Outlook calendar with Gmail calendar, my wife's iPhone calendar, and my Galaxy S2 now running Jellybean.